# Google Search field on website (like Firefox about:home) [not site search]

Tags: search

I am creating an intranet homepage for the company im working at. I would like to integrate a Google search bar (like the one on Firefox's default homepage 'about:home').

I **DONT** want the search to search pages within my site, i simply want it the functionality to be as follows.

- User enters search term in field on intranet homepage
- Hits the search button
- Redirects to Google
- Displays search results

I have searched the web (for a short time) but only found solutions relating to in site searching.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form action="http://www.google.com/search">
    <input name="q">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: This is perfect. Simple and exactly what i needed. Very much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Search API is probably what you want.  You can read all about it [here](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html).

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is your problem?

1. Add a text field to your intranet page
2. Add a submit button to your intranet page
3. On Submit, redirect to `http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=<search term>`